# PHP CURL conversion

Tags: php, curl

Can anyone help correct my code.  I have been passed the API details shown in the comments section at the top and would like to convert into a CURL.  I'm getting errors at the moment (some data changed to protect the real URL etc.)

```
<?php

/*

API DETAILS

Username: foo
password: bar

POST /api/v2/plannedGeofenceVisit HTTP/1.1
Host: dev-mf.testing.co.uk
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic <jumblecode>
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
{
"vehicleIntRef": "vehicleRef",
"bookingRef": 223322,
"shedCode": "test2",
"plannedDispatchDate": "2020-01-25T09:55:00Z",
"estimatedArrivalDate": "2020-02-27T09:55:00Z"
}------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW—


*/

$username = 'foo';
$password = 'bar';

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(CURLOPT_URL => "dev-mf.testing.co.uk",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(      
      "cache-control: no-cache",
      "postman-token: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
      ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
      echo $response;
    }

?>
```

Comment: "I am getting errors at the moment" -> please be more specific; [edit] your question to include *the exact text* of the errors you're seeing.

Comment: What are the error messages, please **edit** your question and show them. Which lines do they refer to, please indicate on the code included.

Comment: The error is 
301 Moved Permanently nginx

Comment: use postman to try. then export to php curl. This works for me a lot of times